# svg question: fill the space with color between two path

Tags: svg

I'm developer, but need to do a quick design with SVG image. And came across an issue. My svg image file is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="160.000000pt" height="157.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 160.000000 157.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.15, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,157.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="red" stroke="none">
<path d="M715 1534 c-191 -31 -370 -134 -489 -280 -55 -67 -118 -192 -143
-284 -27 -101 -25 -293 5 -390 43 -136 97 -226 197 -326 80 -80 104 -98 195
-142 135 -66 235 -87 375 -79 510 28 846 542 664 1018 -87 228 -278 400 -514
463 -61 17 -236 28 -290 20z m285 -191 c176 -58 318 -202 372 -378 31 -97 31
-243 0 -340 -75 -243 -304 -415 -552 -415 -258 0 -486 168 -562 415 -31 97
-31 243 0 340 38 124 120 235 230 309 152 104 333 128 512 69z"/>
<path d="M746 1155 c-48 -17 -94 -59 -113 -105 -11 -24 -17 -86 -21 -199 l-5
-164 -52 58 c-50 56 -52 58 -58 34 -4 -13 -7 -51 -7 -84 l1 -60 87 -93 87 -93
97 88 98 88 0 84 0 84 -22 -19 c-13 -10 -40 -34 -61 -54 l-39 -35 4 152 c3
144 4 153 27 177 46 49 143 42 179 -12 15 -23 17 -54 13 -294 l-3 -268 65 0
65 0 7 284 c7 281 7 285 -15 330 -24 51 -58 79 -121 101 -52 19 -161 19 -213
0z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

And currently, it looks like below:

[image]

This is a u-turn sign. And there are two path: the outer circle and the insider turn. Currently the space between the outer and insider path is transparent. I want to make it blue. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it massively by using simpler shapes. The following needs a little tweaking but is a good starting point:

```html
<svg width="160" height="160" viewBox="0 0 160 160">
  <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="65" fill="skyblue" stroke="red" stroke-width="15" />
  <path stroke="red" stroke-width="12" fill="none" d="M65 103 v-38 a17 17 0 1 1 34 0 v48" />  
  <path fill="red" d="M83 83 v15 l-18 16-18-16v-15l18 16 18-16" />
</svg>
```

### Explanation

Curved line of arrow:

```
<path stroke="red" stroke-width="12" fill="none" 
    d="M65 103              # Move to 65,103
       v-38                 # Vertical line up 38
       a17 17  0 1 1  34 0  # semicircular arc (see below)
       #17 radius
       #       flags
       #              finish 34 to right (34 = 17*2)
       v48                  # vertical line down 48
    " />
```

Arrow Head:

```
<path fill="red" 
d="
    M83 83           # Move to top right corner of arrow head
    v15              # down 15
    l -18 16  -18-16 # \/ shape left (bottom of arrow head)
    v-15             # up 15
    l 18 16  18-16   # \/ shape right (arrow top) to starting point
    # line above could be written 'l18 16 z' for same result
" />
```

Note you can get all fancy creating a [marker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker) element and adding it to the end of the line instead of drawing the arrow head like this ... but that is more complex solution.

Comment: Finessing still required: change radius or thickness of circle to non integer to avoid square edges in non-blink browsers; finessing positioning of line edges to avoid bluriness in non-retina screens; line curve should be ellipse not circle; ... etc etc. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 3):

What I've done: I've recalculated the `viewBox` of your svg element, then I calculated the center of your svg. I've added a blue circle with the center in the center of the svg element.
To get the size of your svg I deleted first the transform and used the `getBBox()` method. I've used the properties of the bounding box for the new `viewBox` value

```css
svg{width:90vh;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="64 32 1506 1506">
  <circle cx="817" cy="785" r="680" fill="skyblue" />
<g 
fill="red" stroke="none">
<path d="M715 1534 c-191 -31 -370 -134 -489 -280 -55 -67 -118 -192 -143
-284 -27 -101 -25 -293 5 -390 43 -136 97 -226 197 -326 80 -80 104 -98 195
-142 135 -66 235 -87 375 -79 510 28 846 542 664 1018 -87 228 -278 400 -514
463 -61 17 -236 28 -290 20z m285 -191 c176 -58 318 -202 372 -378 31 -97 31
-243 0 -340 -75 -243 -304 -415 -552 -415 -258 0 -486 168 -562 415 -31 97
-31 243 0 340 38 124 120 235 230 309 152 104 333 128 512 69z"/>
<path d="M746 1155 c-48 -17 -94 -59 -113 -105 -11 -24 -17 -86 -21 -199 l-5
-164 -52 58 c-50 56 -52 58 -58 34 -4 -13 -7 -51 -7 -84 l1 -60 87 -93 87 -93
97 88 98 88 0 84 0 84 -22 -19 c-13 -10 -40 -34 -61 -54 l-39 -35 4 152 c3
144 4 153 27 177 46 49 143 42 179 -12 15 -23 17 -54 13 -294 l-3 -268 65 0
65 0 7 284 c7 281 7 285 -15 330 -24 51 -58 79 -121 101 -52 19 -161 19 -213
0z"/>
</g> 
</svg>
```

**Observation:** In my code the svg element has a width of 90vh. You may set it to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on enxanetas answer to orient the arrow correctly, here is the code, with all transforms reduced and your viewbox/sizes intact (plus I tidied up the circles):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.0" width="160pt" height="157pt" viewBox="0 0 160 157" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle fill="skyblue" cx="80" cy="78.5" r="58.2"/>
  <path fill="red" stroke="none" d="M 73 41.4 C 68.2 43.1 63.6 47.3 61.7 51.9 C 60.6 54.3 60 60.5 59.6 71.8 L 59.1 88.2 L 53.9 82.4 C 48.9 76.8 48.7 76.6 48.1 79 C 47.7 80.3 47.4 84.1 47.4 87.4 L 47.5 93.4 L 56.2 102.7 L 64.9 112 L 74.6 103.2 L 84.4 94.4 L 84.4 86 L 84.4 77.6 L 82.2 79.5 C 80.9 80.5 78.2 82.9 76.1 84.9 L 72.2 88.4 L 72.6 73.2 C 72.9 58.8 73 57.9 75.3 55.5 C 79.9 50.6 89.6 51.3 93.2 56.7 C 94.7 59 94.9 62.1 94.5 86.1 L 94.2 112.9 L 100.7 112.9 L 107.2 112.9 L 107.9 84.5 C 108.6 56.4 108.6 56 106.4 51.5 C 104 46.4 100.6 43.6 94.3 41.4 C 89.1 39.5 78.2 39.5 73 41.4 Z M 138.2 78.5 C 138.2 46.4 112.1 20.3 80 20.3 C 47.9 20.3 21.8 46.4 21.8 78.5 C 21.8 110.6 47.9 136.7 80 136.7 C 112.1 136.7 138.2 110.6 138.2 78.5 Z M 155.5 78.5 C 155.5 120.2 121.7 154 80 154 C 38.3 154 4.5 120.2 4.5 78.5 C 4.5 36.8 38.3 3 80 3 C 121.7 3 155.5 36.8 155.5 78.5 Z" />
</svg>
```